adot trace collector - version mismatch after updating go.mod dependencies
Had the adot collector for traces and metrics working pretty well for a while.. so I stopped thinking about it.. then someone did a big version update on some shared go.mod files and now Im seeing this error:
│ WARNING : 2024/07/01 18:15:09.469: Failed to connect to telemetry provider:
 conflicting Schema URL: https://opentelemetry.io/schemas/1.25.0 and 
 https://opentelemetry.io/schemas/1.21.0

Its probably time to update the various components in trace/metric pipeline but I can't find where these versions 1.21 / 1.25 appear so I can match.
Everything is running in aws EKS.
